# pre_get_posts on a page

Tags: pre-get-posts

Is it possible to edit the main query on a *page* using the `pre_get_posts` filter?
I tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function pre_wp_queries( $query ) {
    // only trigger on main qyery
    if ( !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if (is_page_template('TEMPLATE_NAME.php')) {
        $query->query_vars['pagename'] = null;
        $query->query_vars['post_type'] = 'post';
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 3;
        $query->query_vars['cat'] = 13;
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_wp_queries', 9001);
```

On the header.php I use this line to check if it worked:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_query']->request);
```

It displays:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

So it changed the posttype but not the rest. Also it goes to the 404 page. In fact dumping the `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->queried_object` gives back the original page. I tried this on 2 WP installs same behaviour on both.

Is this correct behaviour, or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried it in a simpler form? e.g: `function pre_wp_queries($q) { $q->set('posts_per_page', 3); }` Just to see if it works? (tested in a sandbox myself and it works). You may also need to check that there aren't any `query_posts` calls in the template, they will overrule anything done in the `pre_get_posts` hook, afaik.

Comment: Right now I don't even know where I deeded this. I know I 'solved' it / had a work around. Also There was no `query_posts`. I know it's bad for performance. Consider closed.

Answer (score 5):

### Explaining the object.

You don't have to manually *force* data into those class properties. The whole `$wp_query` object has a bunch of internal methods that you should use to **set** values. Here's an example:

```
public function query( $query )
{
    if (
        'SOME_POST_TYPE' !== $query->get( 'post_type' )
        OR ! $query->is_main_query()
        OR ! $query->is_archive()
        OR ! $query->is_post_type_archive()
        OR ! is_page_template( 'TEMPLATE_NAME.php' )
    )
        return $query;

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    $query->set( 'numberposts', -1 );

    return $query;
}
```

### Built in taxonomies: Categories & Tags

#### A Single term/category/taxon

If you want to query for categories and set them manually, then you have a pretty easy task, as you **don't** have to to a `tax_query`:

```
$query->set( 'category__in', 13 );
```

#### Multiple terms/categories/taxons

If you need to query for multiple categories:

```
$query->set( 'category__and', array( 12, 13 ) );
```

You can read more about this on the [Codex page for the `WP_Query` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). And of course you have the same possibilities for the built in `post_tag`/Tags taxonomy.

### Custom taxonomies

Here things *slightly* get more complicated: You'll need to use a `tax_query`. **Keep in mind** that this needs an `array( array() )`. In plain words: One surrounding array and inside this one another one. If you don't do this, WP will fail *silently*. Example:

```
$tax_query = array(
    array(
         'taxonomy' => 'event_type_taxonomy'
        ,'field'    => 'id'
        ,'terms'    => array( 12, 13 )
        ,'operator' =>'IN'
    )
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Extended explanation again on the Codex page.